# Ubuntu 19.10 Mouse Cursor Missing After Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, mouse, cursor

Just installed Ubuntu 19.10 alongside Windows 10 on a Cyberpower tower. Install went smooth after I had trouble using a legacy BIOS, after switching to UEFI. But now ounce I boot into Ubunto the cursor doesn't show. It is working and I can use it to interact but it is totally invisible. I've seen posts of having this issue in older versions and have tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false

sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Still no cursor unfortunately. Should I be using different drivers or something?